# jQuery mobile data-role="button" not formatting

Tags: jquery-mobile, button

I'm loading into another div with .load('settings.html') function in

The settings.html page being loaded contains:

```
<div style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid black">
    Application Settings: <br>
    <a href="#" onclick="resetApp()" data-role="button">Reset Application Key</a>
</div>
```

The problem is that the button is not getting formatted as per jquery mobile button data-role. If I place this on my main page the button is displayed correctly whereas by load function its a simple link.

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you load settings.html use `enhanceWithin()` to enhance the markup and css of the button. Give your div a class and enhance it after load

Read more here -- https://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/

**Demo** Take out the enhance to see that it does not render properly even when you append it

https://jsfiddle.net/5es81kgd/

**Code**

```
$('.but').append('<a href="#" onclick="resetApp()" data-role="button">Reset Application Key</a>').enhanceWithin();
```

Comment: This works perfectly with .append(), trying now with .load() (as specified in question) but it doesn't seem to work. Or is .load() the wrong function to use to load an external page?

Comment: @Fabrizio Mazzoni load should be ok. did you give your div a class?? and enhance it after load

Comment: Sorted. Changed to $.get and applying .enhanceWithin() after function and now working!

Comment: @Fabrizio Mazzoni -- ok, so it needs ajax to load the data into the page properly

Comment: Yes. It does need ajax